# Problem with update_field of ACF img associated with User

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an edit profile page with a form POST, in which there's an input file, that upload image via ajax on the server and in the media library and return the filename in a textarea.
I can't update field with the url of the image that I uploaded via ajax. The Image appears in the media library and in server folder, but my acf field doesn't update.
The field is set to return img link.
This is my code:

```
$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();     
$filename_path = $wp_upload_dir['path'] . "/$img"; //img is the value of POST of the textarea and return the filename "ARCW8764.JPG"
$filename_url = $wp_upload_dir['url'] ."/$img";
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename_path), null );  
    
                                       
$attachment = array(
'guid'=> $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename_path ),
'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
'post_title' => $img,
'post_content' => '',
'post_status' => 'inherit'
);
                        
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment);
    
update_field('foto-agente',$filename_url,$user);
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Given that everything else is correct. Probably you are not targeting the field correctly. You need to go to the database in the table that is stored. I am guessing either `wp_postmeta` or `wp_usermeta` and check the name of your field. It is probably something like `something_foto-agente`. This is how ACF is storing nested fields, ex: `parent_child_grandchild_name-of-field`.

/* if the field has no record, you will not find it. Ensure to store something from the admin first, then see the name of the field in DB and then try it from your code. Let me know, good luck!